# Заполнение динамического двумерного массива случайными числами

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, динамические-массивы

Помогите.Что нужно изменить,чтобы программа заработала?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <ctime>
#include "math.h"
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;



int** sozdanie(int **matr,int n, int m)
{
    // Создаем матрицу введенной размерности
    matr = new int *[n]; // через массив указателей
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        matr[i] = new int[m];
    }
    return matr;
}
//------------Генерация случайных значений--------------------------
int**  RndDArray(int **matr, int n,int m, int a, int b){

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)

    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)

        matr[i][j] = a + rand() % (b - a + 1);
    return matr;
}

int main() {

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
int n=8, m=8,a=1,b=10;//n и m – количество строк и столбцов матрицы 
int **matr; //указатель для массива указателей
matr = new int *[n]; //выделение динамической памяти под массив указателей
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    matr[i] = new int[m]; //выделение динамической памяти для массива значений

sozdanie(matr,n, m);
RndDArray(matr, n, m, a, b);
cout << endl;
cout << "Заполнение массива случайными числами" << endl;

    cout << matr<< "  " << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что сейчас не так с программой? Опишите в чем проблема? Ошибка вылетает или результат не тот, который ожидали?

Comment: @Павел не выводит на экран заполненный массив. Только адрес

Comment: Понятное дело, вам нужно каждый элемент отдельно выводить.

Comment: @Павел Покажите ,пожалуйста, как это сделать

Comment: Пройтись циклами по всем элементам. У вас функция `RndDArray` устанавливает значение каждому элементу матрицы, а теперь вам нужно вывести каждый элемент матрицы!

Comment: `for (i = 0; i<8; i++)
{
 for (j = 0; j<8; j++)
 {
  matr[i][j] = rand() % 100;
  cout<<"%4d"<< matr[i][j];
 }
 cout<<"\n";
} `

Comment: @Павел добавил цикл, но выводит адреса

Comment: А зачем "%4d"???

Comment: @Павел понято+принято. Теперь все работает как нужно. Спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score -1):

sozdanie(matr,n, m); лишняя? Вы чуть выше выделяете память.

Заполняете правильно,

cout << matr<< "  " << endl; - неправильно. Выводится адрес.
Снова пройдитесь по массиву так-же, как заполняете.